# Trying to read response from Web API call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to read my employees list from a Web API call but getting errors.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
   client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://myApiUrl");
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

   HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/hr/employees");
   if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
   {
      List<Employee> employees = response.Content.ReadAsAsync(IEnumerable<Employee>).Result;
   }
}
```

The error I'm currently getting is:
System.Net.Http.HttpContent does not contain a definition for ReadAsAsync...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: > *`ReadAsAsync(IEnumerable<Employee>)`*: Hold on what are you trying to do here? That's invalid syntax. Did you mean to use generics? `typeof`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReadAsAsync is not a method on the HttpClient class. If you want to read the data and cast it to an object you can use:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/hr/employees");
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var result= await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    List<Employee> employees = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee>(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
List<Employee> employees = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Employee>>().Result;
```